# Best way to detect features based on text

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text-mining

I have a "simple" problem: I have text sections and based on this it should be decided its whether "Category A" or "Category B".

As training data I have classified sections of text, which the algorithm can be trained.

The text sections look something like this:

### Category A

```
a blue car drives
```

or

```
the blue bus stops
```

or

```
the blue bike drives
```

### Category B

```
 a red bike drives
```

or

```
 the red bus stops
```

(The section text contains up to 20 words and the vary is massive)

If I have trained the algorithm with this example data, it should decide if text contains "blue" it's Categorie A, if its contains "red" it's Categorie B and so on.

The algorithm should learn based on training data if the frequency of a word is it likely more Category A or B.

Whats the best way to do this and which tool should I use?

Comment: what features have you included in your feature vector so far? What classifier to you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Fisher method](https://www.inkling.com/read/program-collective-intelligence-toby-segaran-1st/chapter-6/the-fisher-method), in which the probability of both positive (A) and negative (B) for each feature word (red, blue) in the document are calculated. The probability that a sentence with each of the two specified word (red, blue) belongs in the specified category (A, B) is obtained, assuming there will be an equal number of items in each category. Then a combined probability is obtained.

Since the features are not independent, this won’t be a real probability, but it works much like the Bayesian classifier. The value returned by the Fisher method is a much better estimate of probability, which can be very useful when reporting results or deciding cutoffs.

Answer (score 0):

I think a fisrt try should be [Logistic Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) as you have a binary classification problem. As soon as you have defined you caracteristic vector (e.g., frequency of a set of determined words) you can optimize the parameters of cost function that is for binary classification (e.g, [the sigmoid funcion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) ).

An step that you probably will need is to eliminate ['stop words'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words).

I really recommend the [Coursera Machine Learning classes](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml).